# What's the running coupling of gravity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, renormalization, effective-field-theory

Pictures like the one below are often used to talk about grand unification.

[image]

I've never heard any physics textbook really talk about the running of the *gravitational* coupling constant $G$, but some popsci sources seem to vaguely imply that gravity should have a line on this diagram too, and it joins up with the others at the TOE scale.

Is there a way to make this statement precise? If so, what would gravity look like on this plot?

Comment: Of course the gravitational coupling also runs. However, in contrast to the other coupling strengths, it is dimensionful. So the running is almost entirely given by $\mu^2/M_\mathrm{P}^2$, which unifies with the other couplings around $\mu_\mathrm{unification}\sim M_\mathrm{P}$. In theories with extra dimensions one can change this to obtain $\mu_\mathrm{unification}=M_\mathrm{GUT}$.

Comment: Do you want to know about the running of $G_N$ according to *what* theory? naïve quantum gravity? supergravity? string theory? All these theories predict different runnings. More generally, the running of a certain parameter depends on the complete theory you are embedding it into.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You don't need a grand unified theory to talk about the running of couplings below the GUT scale. Neither do you need a UV complete theory of quantum gravity to talk about the running of $G$.

Comment: @knzhou I didn't say you do. What you *do* need is to specify the context. There are an infinite number of theories that implement gravitation at a quantum level. They predict different runnings for $G_N$. Without the context, the question is meaningless. You *could* argue that any realistic theory agrees in the IR, and therefore agrees in the running of $G_N$ for small energy. But you didn't specify that you only care about the IR. Thus, the question needs some more details to be meaningful (FWIW, I *do* like the question anyway, don't get me wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course the gravitational coupling also runs. However, in contrast to the other coupling strengths, it is dimensionful. So the running is almost entirely given by $\mu^2/M_\mathrm{P}^2$, which unifies with the other couplings around $\mu_\mathrm{unification}\sim M_\mathrm{P}$. In theories with extra dimensions one can change this by bringing down the Planck scale to obtain $μ_\mathrm{unification}\simeq M_\mathrm{GUT}$. This requires a parametrically largish volume of the compactified dimensions.

In string theory, the analogous question is to reconcile the GUT and string scales, which has triggered [some of the most important developments of the field](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9602070).

Answer (score 0):

I personally also think, that it is running, as it is described by Asymptotic Safey or measured by Causal Dynamical Triangulations. But in order to have a consistent 1-loop correction of GR, there is no need for a running G, as it is treated as an effective field theory by John Donoghue in his paper. So it depends on the theory.